# REACT: how tell parent component about invalid data from child?

Tags: reactjs

I have a child component that renders a list (after processing some complex logic) that is passed to it from parent using props

**Problem**

If parent passes an invalid list then child renders nothing and parent shows a empty `li`

I want to check if child has not rendered any thing so that `li` can be removed.

Comment: Not sure I understand... Is it not possible to validate data in parent before being passed to child?

Comment: If I do it then I will have to iterate through the list in parent and child both. should I do it? is there a way for child to know its parent that its not rendering anything or the data is invalid?

Comment: Hard to give a concrete answer without looking at both parent and child codebase...

Comment: render `li` in child ?

Comment: @xadm that is not possible as the component is reusable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introducing new dependency (noticing parent) won't help in reusability.

You shouldn't provide bad data to components - filter them before passing down.

Obvious answer is to not render `li` externally - render it inside a child.

**To preserve reusability pass this `<li />` as a `'tag' or 'component' prop` to child and render conditionally (decorate content) when defined.** It's quite common pattern in react. You can also use render props pattern.